# Return reference to *this without a copy constructor?

Tags: c++11, copy-constructor, move-constructor, return-by-reference, return-by-value

I've written a class similar to the following:

```cpp
class ScriptThread {
public:
    ScriptThread(): mParent() {}

private:
    ScriptThread(ScriptThread *parent): mParent(parent) {}

public:
    ScriptThread(ScriptThread &&rhs);
    ScriptThread &operator = (ScriptThread &&rhs);
    // copy constructor/assignment deleted implicitly

    ScriptThread &execute(const Script &script);
    ScriptThread spawn();
    ScriptThread spawn(const Script &script);

private:
    ScriptThread *mParent;
};

ScriptThread &ScriptThread::execute(const Script &script) {
    // start executing the given script
    return *this;
}

ScriptThread ScriptThread::spawn() {
    // create a ScriptThread with "this" as its parent
    return ScriptThread(this);
}

ScriptThread ScriptThread::spawn(const Script &script) {
    // convenience method to spawn and execute at the same time
    return spawn().execute(script); // ERROR: "use of deleted function"
}
```

As written, g++ fails to compile it at the line marked "ERROR", claiming that it's trying to use the (deleted) copy constructor.  However, if I replace the last function with this:

```cpp
ScriptThread ScriptThread::spawn(const Script &script) {
    ScriptThread thread = spawn();
    thread.execute(script);
    return thread;
}
```

It compiles without an error.  Even after referring to a number of articles, references, and other SO questions, I don't understand: why does the first invoke the copy constructor at all?  Isn't the move constructor enough?

Comment: The return type of `execute()` is `ScriptThread&`.  This is an lvalue reference, not convertible to `ScriptThread&&`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ScriptThread` is noncopyable (the implicit copy constructor/assignment operators are defined as deleted because you declared move constructor/assignment). In `spawn()`, your original implementation:

```
ScriptThread ScriptThread::spawn(const Script &script) {
    return spawn().execute(script);
}
```

is attempting to construct a `ScriptThread` from an *lvalue* reference (`execute` returns a `ScriptThread&`). That will call the copy constructor, which is deleted, hence the error.

However, in your second attempt:

```
ScriptThread ScriptThread::spawn(const Script &script) {
    ScriptThread thread = spawn();
    thread.execute(script);
    return thread;
}
```

we run into the rule, from [class.copy]:

> When the criteria for elision of a copy/move operation are met, but not for an exception-declaration, and the
>   object to be copied is designated by an lvalue, **or when the expression in a return statement is a (possibly
>   parenthesized) *id-expression* that names an object with automatic storage duration declared in the body** or
>   *parameter-declaration-clause* of the innermost enclosing function or *lambda-expression*, overload resolution
>   to select the constructor for the copy is first performed **as if the object were designated by an rvalue**.

Even though `thread` is an lvalue, we perform overload resolution on the constructor of `ScriptThread` as if it were an rvalue. And we do have a valid constructor for this case: your move constructor/assignment.

That's why the replacement is valid (and uses move construction), but the original failed to compile (because it required copy construction).

Comment: Elision is not really the crucial thing here; it doesn't affect the well-formedness of code. You need the "implicitly treated as rvalue in return" rule.

Comment: @T.C. Added. I mean, it's half the crucial thing. You need the elision criteria to get to that rule.

Comment: Not really. The "or when the expression in a return statement..." clause handles this case already.

Comment: @T.C. But `spawn().execute(script);` isn't an *id-expression*

Comment: And that's why it isn't treated as an rvalue.  I agree elision is not really relevant. `execute(script)` returns an lvalue, so can't be moved from. Despite the OP's surprise, that case should be completely obvious. You can't move from lvalues. The fact `return thread;` _can_ be moved should be surprising, but there is a special case for `return thread;` that allows it to be moved from, because `thread` is about to go out of scope so can be treated as an xvalue.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Oh I see what you guys are saying now. Ok, lemme rewrite this.

Comment: Guess I didn't think about this long enough.  *I* know the returned reference (in the first version) is also (ultimately) to a temporary object, but of course the compiler can't assume that.  @JonathanWakely:  Yes, my confusion was mostly caused by expecting the compiler to treat each situation the same way; I'm still getting used to things like rvalue-references and move semantics.

Comment: Yes exactly, `execute()` returns an lvalue, so the compiler has to treat is as an lvalue. If you wanted to get "clever" you could overload `execute` to return an rvalue when invoked on an rvalue ([example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a5b8835bc139bbcd)) but it's probably not worth it.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Heh, I was *this* close to adding that onto my answer earlier.

Answer (score 3):

`execute(script)` returns an lvalue. You can't implicitly move from an lvalue, so to use the move constructor for the returned object you would need to say

```
return std::move(spawn().execute(script));
```

You didn't do this so it tries to use the copy constructor, because that's how you make new objects from lvalues.

In your replacement case you have:

```
return thread;
```

Here `thread` is also an lvalue, *but* it's about to go out of scope as soon as the function ends, so conceptually it can be considered to be like a temporary or other variable that is going to disappear at the end of the expression. Because of this there is a special rule in the C++ standard that says the compiler treats such local variables as rvalues, allowing the move constructor to be used *even though `thread` is really an lvalue*.

See Barry's more complete answer for the references to the standard where the special rule is defined, and the full details of the rule.

Comment: I'm accepting Barry's answer primarily for the extra detail and reference to the standard, but I am going to use `std::move` in place of what I have; it's much more concise.  Thanks to both of you for your help.